# How can I increase firebase database read time and prevent timeout from Nginx

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database, concurrency, firebase-cloud-messaging

Context: I try to build a chat service. In chat service, I have (Say: 50000+) chat rooms. 
I have 20 admins who can access some specific chat rooms (Say: can access around 5000 chat rooms). So, I want to create features, so that I can add new admin and get the chat room list based on my query (Say: I got 5000 chat room from my query),  add that new admin to on those 5000 chat room using a single endpoint. I am using Golang and Firebase.

```
//GetAdmin user take a userID and it's return a user.
func GetAdminUser(userID int) (user *User, err error) {
    // It will query on the database 
    // then return the a user
    return user, nil
}
```

The problem is when I pass the patient's list and try to read the patient's topic from the firebase database It took around 20 minutes to read. So, it will give time out on Nginx.

Is there any way I can improve firebase read time using go concurrency or any other way I can improve the reading from firebase and adding them without cazing any timeout error.

```
func AddNewAdminToPatientTopics(ctx context.Context, user User, patients []User) error {
    for _, patient := range patients {
        oldTopics := firebase.database.NewRef(fmt.Sprintf("USER_TOPICS/%d", patient.ID))
        for topicID, t := range topics {
            newUserTopics := firebase.database.NewRef(fmt.Sprintf("USER_TOPICS/%d/%s", user.ID, topicID))

            // Add this new admin as a participant in this topic
            topic := firebase.database.NewRef(fmt.Sprintf("TOPICS/%s/Participants/%d", topicID, user.ID))
            participant := &Participant{
                UserID: strconv.Itoa(user.ID),
                LastTimeSeenOnline: time.Now().Unix(),
                .......
            }
            err = topic.Set(ctx, participant)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}


func AddManager(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Don't worry about error, I handle them gracefully

    // Get User
    user, err := GetAdminUser(UserID)

    // get patients list
    // Say, In this case you we have 5000+ patients
    patients, err := GetPatients(user.CustomerID)


    // Join this user to all chat rooms that the first admin has
    err = AddNewAdminToTopics(context.Background(), *user, patients)
}

Routers: 

http.HandleFunc("chat/managers/new/add", Post).Then(clinic.AddManager))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't perform huge read or write operations on your real database please. While the server is processing that huge read/write, it is not servicing requests from your clients.

For this type of processing, I'd highly recommend setting up automatic backups in the Firebase console, and then performing the operation on the raw data from that backup. That way you can optimize how you process the data, to not be dependent on the response time of the Firebase Database servers.

Of course you'll still depend on the Firebase servers for the write operations. I'd consider doing that in reasonably sized multi-location updates, where you ensure that each multi-location update takes no more than a few seconds at most.